# Array error "error: array required, but int found" when trying to merge the balls

Tags: java

Okay, so basically I'm trying to create an Agario like game and not I'm at the stage where I try to merge the balls, if I (the player) is larger than the enemy I eat them and gain their mass but if the enemy is larger it eats me and I lose.
I've been trying to solve this issue for a while now and I'm not getting anywhere, I've tried to google it and even ask my teacher for a solution which he could not come up with.

This is the part where I am having trouble.

```
        for (int i=0;i<antal;i++) {
            Point fiende = new Point((int)ritduk.enemyXpos[i], (int)ritduk.enemyYpos[i]);
            Point spelare = new Point(ritduk.playerX, ritduk.playerY);
            if (spelare.distance(fiende)<(ritduk.playerSize+ritduk.enemyXYsize[i])/3) {
                System.out.println("spelare");
                if (ritduk.playerSize>ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]) {
                    ritduk.playerSize+=ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]/2;
                    ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]=0;
             if (fiende.distance(spelare)<(ritduk.enemyXYsize+ritduk.playerSize[i])/3) {
                System.out.println("motsåndare");
                if (ritduk.enemyXYsize>ritduk.playerSize[i]) {
                    ritduk.enemyXYsize+=ritduk.playerSize[i]/2;
                    ritduk.playerSize[i]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the full program:

```
public class bloop implements KeyListener {

Ritabloop ritduk;
boolean wPressed, aPressed, sPressed, dPressed;

public bloop() {
    JFrame fonster = new JFrame();
    fonster = new JFrame("Bloop Spel");
    fonster.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ritduk = new Ritabloop();
    fonster.add(ritduk);
    fonster.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,800));
    fonster.pack();

    int antal = 10;

    double[] enemyXpos = new double[antal];
    double[] enemyYpos = new double[antal];
    double[] enemyXYsize = new double[antal];
    double[] enemyXspeed = new double[antal];
    double[] enemyYspeed = new double[antal];

    fonster.setVisible(true);
    fonster.addKeyListener(this);

    for (int i=0; i<antal; i++) {
        enemyXpos[i] = (Math.random()*900);
        enemyYpos[i] = (Math.random()*700);
        enemyXspeed[i] = (Math.random()*4-2);
        enemyYspeed[i] = (Math.random()*4-2);
        enemyXYsize[i] = (Math.random()*40+40);
    }
    ritduk.enemyXpos = enemyXpos;
    ritduk.enemyYpos = enemyYpos;
    ritduk.enemyXYsize = enemyXYsize;

    while(true) {
        if (dPressed) ritduk.playerX = ritduk.playerX+5;
        if (aPressed) ritduk.playerX = ritduk.playerX-5;
        if (wPressed) ritduk.playerY = ritduk.playerY-5;
        if (sPressed) ritduk.playerY = ritduk.playerY+5;
        if (ritduk.playerX>900) ritduk.playerX=900;
        if (ritduk.playerY>700) ritduk.playerY=700;
        if (ritduk.playerX<0) ritduk.playerX=0;
        if (ritduk.playerY<0) ritduk.playerY=0;

        for (int i=0;i<antal;i++) {
            Point fiende = new Point((int)ritduk.enemyXpos[i], (int)ritduk.enemyYpos[i]);
            Point spelare = new Point(ritduk.playerX, ritduk.playerY);
            if (spelare.distance(fiende)<(ritduk.playerSize+ritduk.enemyXYsize[i])/3) {
                System.out.println("spelare");
                if (ritduk.playerSize>ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]) {
                    ritduk.playerSize+=ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]/2;
                    ritduk.enemyXYsize[i]=0;
             if (fiende.distance(spelare)<(ritduk.enemyXYsize+ritduk.playerSize[i])/3) {
                System.out.println("motsåndare");
                if (ritduk.enemyXYsize>ritduk.playerSize[i]) {
                    ritduk.enemyXYsize+=ritduk.playerSize[i]/2;
                    ritduk.playerSize[i]=0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            if (enemyXpos[i]+enemyXYsize[i]>=900 || enemyXpos[i]<0) {
                enemyXspeed[i] = -1*enemyXspeed[i];
            }
            if (enemyYpos[i]+enemyXYsize[i]>=700 || enemyYpos[i]<0) {
                enemyYspeed[i] = -1*enemyYspeed[i];
            }
            enemyXpos[i] = enemyXpos[i] + enemyXspeed[i];
            enemyYpos[i] = enemyYpos[i] + enemyYspeed[i];
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
        ritduk.repaint();
    }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='d') {
        dPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='a') {
        aPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='w') {
        wPressed = true;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='s') {
        sPressed = true;
    }
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='d') {
        dPressed=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='a') {
        aPressed=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='w') {
        wPressed=false;
    }
    if (e.getKeyChar()=='s') {
        sPressed=false;
    }
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new bloop();
}
}
```

and this is the other half:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Ritabloop extends JPanel {

int playerX=200,playerY=200, playerSize=100;
double[] enemyXpos,enemyYpos,enemyXYsize;

Color playerColor = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));
Color enemyColor = new Color((int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255),(int)(Math.random()*255));

public void paint(Graphics u) {
    u.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    u.fillRect(0,0,1000,800);
    u.setColor(playerColor);
    u.fillOval(playerX,playerY,playerSize,playerSize);
    u.setColor(enemyColor);
    for (int i=0; i<enemyXpos.length; i++) {
        u.fillOval((int)enemyXpos[i], (int)enemyYpos[i], (int)enemyXYsize[i], (int)enemyXYsize[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: which line you got error on?add the stack trace.

Comment: @AshishMishra now added the code part where I am having the problems, keep in mind that this code is written in Swedish but I think you still understand it, if not just ask me for the translation I guess.

Comment: The error can be possibly due to double and int conversion or using integer instead of the array would suggest rechecking all assignment statements

Comment: @AshishMishra || error: array required, but int found ritduk.playerSize[i]=0; || array required, but int found ritduk.enemyXYsize+=ritduk.playerSize[i]/2; || error: array required, but int found if (ritduk.enemyXYsize>ritduk.playerSize[i]) { || array required, but int found if (fiende.distance(spelare<(ritduk.enemyXYsize+ritduk.playerSize[i])/3) { || This is the errors I'm receiving and not quiet understanding what you mean with the comment.

Answer (score 0):

In `Class Ritabloop` you have declared `int playerX=200,playerY=200, playerSize=100;` playerSize as integer but using it as an Array of integers.

```
if (fiende.distance(spelare)<(ritduk.enemyXYsize+ritduk.playerSize[i])/3) {
 System.out.println("motsåndare");
 if (ritduk.enemyXYsize>ritduk.playerSize[i]) {
     ritduk.enemyXYsize+=ritduk.playerSize[i]/2;
     ritduk.playerSize[i]=0;
     }
 }
```